# И еще о русаках

Tags: этимология

Пока писал предыдущий вопрос, возник следующий.
Есть заяц беляк — это понятно, он зимой белый, а есть русак, который не меняет окрас. Так вот, почему он так называется? Связано это как-то со словом "русский" или все-таки с "русый" (что-то не очень похож цвет его шерсти на русые волосы)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имена зайцы получили благодаря своему внешнему виду и только. Заяц-русак летом и зимой остаётся серого, русого цвета, оттого и назван русаком.

По Ефремовой:
http://tolkslovar.ru/r7755.html  Русый - 1. Светло-коричневый с сероватым или желтоватым оттенком (обычно о волосах, реже - о шерсти животного). 
2. Имеющий волосы такого цвета (о человеке).

Русак именно такой окрас и имеет - светло-коричневый с серым оттенком.